# IIS web server and thread pool issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, threadpool

Question is related ASP.NET 4.0 and IIS based azure cloud service:

1. need to know right number of IOCP threads to set for production web service where we make 10-20K/sec remote calls
2. Also need to know right number of Worker threads to set for production web service...specially to handle 10-20K/sec API calls...specially in bursts
3. Basically, I am facing issue that each of my cloud service VM should handle 10-20K requests/sec but it is not able to do so due to thread pool issue w.r.t. asp.net
4. my prod service does nothing but get data from redis and simply return

Comment: Sorry, but this is a very hard question to answer without a whole lot more information: current performance, what the nature of the calls is (size of request and typical response, how taxing any auth is that you're doing, etc), how much memory the service consumes and how much is allocated, how many cores are allocated, whether the service spins up extra threads, are there any blocking calls made within the service, and so on.  I think the best answer is to check the service code for efficiency and test different configurations and find what is causing the bottleneck in your particular setup.

Comment: Performance tuning requires a thorough analysis of your code base and production setup. Hire a consultant or open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: lets say, there are no memory limitation, no auth, request-response size if extremely small, 4 core machine, no other service calls
Also, as I said, this is a plain REST API that calls redis and send back the fetched data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming code is efficient and there is enough hardware i.e. there are no issues related to memory, cpu and n/w:
1. You should try to keep IOCP to minimal numbers 50-100
2. You should try to keep CPU threads to high to handle bursts of requests

I am not sure if it's a good idea to keep 2-5K active threads to cater to 10-20K requests/sec